# Trouble installing Tensorflow on Windows 10 Error trace related to Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, tensorflow

I have python 3.6 and get this message after running pip install

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I had auto-installed Python from my Visual Studio Community Edition pack that can with the program.

`Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 2                               15, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", l                               ine 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 7                               84, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", li                               ne 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", li                               ne 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in                                move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in                                clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Li                               b\\site-packages\\protobuf-3.3.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth'`

Comment: These answers didn't help? (for instance the `--user` parameter) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816674/pip-is-not-able-to-install-packages-correctly-permission-denied-error

Comment: Another option is that you currently have some python version running. Make sure you have stopped all python processes before trying to call pip install.

Comment: Now I tried installing via `pip -install -user tensorflow-gpu` as suggested, but after running the `activate tensorflow-gpu` command I receive this error `source activate envname` which I enter and still nothing?

Comment: After writing `source activate envname` command I keep getting this same trace error dealing with Anaconda: `$ source activate envname
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: `
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 15                                  4, in main
    activate.main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\activate.py", lin                                  e 160, in main
    prefix = prefix_from_arg(sys.argv[3], shelldict=shelldict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\activate.py", lin