# Permission denied with trying to use pip on MAC?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, permissions, pip

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info'Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

The error above is the one I get when I try to use the pip command. All I need to do is pip install the requirements.txt to get my program to work.  I have python 2.7.1 installed and placed my code where I am able to use python commands. I tried to change permissions by using this command:

```
chmod -R 777
```

but it did not work. I have homebrew installed on my computer. I also tried to use a virtual environment using this link:
http://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/virtualenv.html but it gave me permission issues as well. Is there any suggestions to get rid of this permissions issue and run pip successfully? The sudo command below also doesn't work.

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a permissions issue.

Consider using `pip install "packagename" --user` as mentioned in the error.
This is covered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816674/pip-is-not-able-to-install-packages-correctly-permission-denied-error)

Comment: tried this and I still have some permission issues, but the link helped the most so thanks

Comment: I tried this, and the package appears to have installed successfully, **pip install python-docx --user
Collecting python-docx
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from python-docx) (4.2.3)
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: python-docx
Successfully installed python-docx-0.8.6**

 the package is not showing in my site-packages folder and I can't use it.  Mac high sierra, python 3.7, Pycharm 2018.  Thanks.

Comment: I used the --user flag and it said "Successfully installed pip-18.1" but then I get "-bash: pip: command not found" when I try to use it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try using `sudo pip install djangorestframework` for Mac. Worked for me.

Comment: Be very careful about doing `sudo` during package installation. It gives root access to possibly malicious packages. It's best to use `--user` to insulate things from the rest of the system
https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the directory where the package's entry point was installed is not in your PATH. For example, if it was installed /Users/username/Library/Python/3.7/bin/script, add PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Python/3.7/bin/ to your shell rc (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc), and you should be good (and that will solve issues with other scripts installed to that /bin folder.